# mongoengine and django rest framework - fields aren't allowed to be optional

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I've setup a REST api with django rest framework, using mongoengine as the ORM for my models. However, I keep getting this response back from the api for a field that should be optional:

```
{"ref":["This field may not be null."]}
```

The problem I'm running into is that it seems like all fields (I'm specifically using `ReferenceFields`, but I've tried it with `StringFields`, etc too) are not allowed to be optional/null.

I've tried setting validation methods to an empty lambda (that returns `True`), setting `null=True` and `required=False` where the field is defined in the model.

```
from mongoengine import *

class B(Document):
    ...    

class A(Document):
    ref = ReferenceField('B', null=True, required=False, dbref=False, validation=lambda: True)
```

I even tried explicitly setting the serializer in A's serializer so that I could tell it to allow nulls (with `allow_null=True`):

```
from api.models import A,B
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer

class BSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        depth = 2

class ASerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    ref = BSerializer(allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        depth = 2
```

How do I get optional (nullable) fields to work with django rest framework and mongoengine? Again, this isn't just `ReferenceFields`, it's the same with any field I try.

Comment: Just so it's clear, I am explicitly setting the ref field to null (as opposed to omitting the field) when using the REST api.

Comment: This sounds like a `rest_framework_mongoengine` issue, it should be setting `allow_none` on the DRF field if `null` is set on the document field.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like a good direction. I'll see about getting a pull request submitted

Comment: Anything further with this?

Comment: @Wtower haha good question :^) this was a long time ago... iirc I might have just worked around it. I'll see if I can dig up what I did